# Accessing multiple images from a .mat file array

Tags: arrays, image, matlab

I have a Matlab .mat file, Images.mat, a 60000 x 784 array where each row corresponds to a 28 x 28 image.  I'm having trouble finding a way to access each image one at a time to later use for an assignment in optical character recognition.  I have had no luck using imshow or imagesc, so any tips would be quite helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = reshape(array.', 28, 28,[]);
```

Now `array(:,:,1)` contains image 1 etc, so you could do for example `imshow(array(:,:,1))`.